# Define an array within calling of a function in java

Tags: java, arrays, function

Currently I have the code that is below.

```
String[] ans = {"Yes","No"};
option = questionAsk("Are you sure?",ans);
```

I have tried simply sticking the definition of 'ans' into the call of the function and have tried to change it around but I cannot seem to find how to make these two lines become one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define an array when calling a method:

`option = questionAsk("Are you sure?", new String[]{"Yes","No"});`

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I tried but left 'ans =' in the middle of the array definition!
Thanks for your help!!!